# How to set a JSONB value to null

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

I'm trying to update a bunch of jsonb values to null. Here's an example of what i'm trying to do and i'm getting the error below.

How can I set `first-name` to null in this case?

```
UPDATE users
SET
    fields = fields || '{"first-name": NULL}'
WHERE user_id = 1;
```

```
ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type json
LINE 3:  fields = fields || '{"first-name": NULL}'
                                    ^
DETAIL:  Token "NULL" is invalid.
CONTEXT:  JSON data, line 1: {"first-name": NULL...
```

Comment: In my case, I actually need to set multiple fields to null

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want the `null` value inside the JSONB, then it must be a JSON null value, not an SQL NULL value.  JSON `null` must be spelled in lower case.

Comment: I was able to set multiple fields using my original syntax with this suggestion of changing to lowercase null.

Answer (score 6):

Use `jsonb_set`:

```
UPDATE users
SET
    fields = jsonb_set(fields, '{first-name}', 'null')
WHERE user_id = 1;
```

Comment: How would I set multiple fields to null in that case?

Comment: By nesting several function calls.

Comment: Can you provide an example?

Comment: Replace the second `fields` in my answer with another call to `jsonb_set`.

Comment: I have like 60 fields that need to be set to null though. By nesting all those jsonb_set's it'll be super ugly and unreadable

Comment: Using JSON instead of a proper relational model is bound to make processing ugly and slow. You can encapsulate the ugliness in a function that loops.